# Updating to a much higher mediawiki script?

Tags: mediawiki

I currently have `1.23.1` installed and would like to update to ´1.30´ and got bunch of extensions installed. What would be the best way to update the wiki? Should I update version by version or jump straight the the final version that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real benefit in updating version by version; the upgrade script just applies DB schema changes from each version successively, so mostly the result will be the same both ways. If something breaks, going step by step and testing after each step will tell you which version broke it, and thus you are in a better position fixing/reporting it, but it's usually not too hard to figure that out anyway and it would be a vast time sink.

Comment: The one exception is the [hit counter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HitCounters) which has been removed in a somewhat unfortunate manner. If you need that data, you need to make the update in two steps (or dump and port it manually).